# How do I save localstorage timestamp and get the difference?

Tags: javascript

I want to set localstorage' a timestamp. The time timestamp I set should be subtracted from the current time. What i want to do is a countdown

```
funcion setLocalStorage(){
           localStorage.setItem("countDown", new Date().toString());
                         }

funcion getLocalStorage(){
           return localStorage.getItem("countDown");
                         }

let diff = new Date() - getLocalStorage()
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.setItem("countDown", new Date().getTime());`

then

`let diff = new Date().getTime() - Number(getLocalStorage())`

Comment: I know that localstorage only accepts strings

Comment: You don't need to call `toString()` though, you just need to convert to a number when you want to subtract the vallue

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem("countDown", Date.now());
}

function getLocalStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem("countDown");
}

let diff = Date.now() - getLocalStorage();
```